# How to define minimum JRE requirement (1.5 _or higher_)?

Tags: osgi, compatibility, java

OSGi manifest entry "bundleRequiredExecutionEnvironment" can be used to specify JRE on which given bundle can be used on, but it seems like this is a strict check such that if I specify value of "J2SE-1.5", bundle could not be used on 1.6 or above. This seems strange; my assumption was that this would just be the baseline, not exact match.

But if the semantic of property are exact match, what would be the way to indicate "1.5 or higher"? Or could this be a bug of OSGi container in question misinterpreting requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have to specify all of the valid JRE environments.

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5, JavaSE-1.6
```

When Java 1.7 becomes available, you'll have to add that as well.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll see if I can find a web page to confirm this (ability to define multiple choices)

Comment: Ok: yes, section 4.5 does confirm that multiple values are allowed for this property, and that behavior is match to see that environments are available. I guess I will add JavaSE-1.6 in there for now, and JavaSE-1.7 once